# Se pierden datos en el proceso Controlador - Vista - Controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

les comento que tengo 2 controladores, uno para el GET y otro para el POST que voy a editar para que se entienda más facilmente:

```
// GET: Compras/Create
public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {

       ComprasCreateModel compra = new ComprasCreateModel();

       compra.ClienteId = id;
       compra.NombreCliente = db.Clientes.Find(id).Nombre;

       return View(compra);

    }


// POST: Compras/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ComprasCreateModel compra)
    {

        if (compra.ClienteId == 0)
          return View(A);
        else
          return View(B);

    }
```

Y sucede, que mi Vista Create presenta un formulario para llenar:

model.Edad

model.Telefono

Por lo tanto, lo unico que se cambia del modelo en la Vista es esas propiedades. Y al hacer click en el submitButton se llama al controlador del POST.

Pero si desde el GET se le pasó un modelo compra con las propiedades ClienteId y NombreCliente, ¿por qué el resultado final es que me muestra la Vista A?

Es decir, al POST de Create llega compra.ClienteId con valor 0, y compra.NombreCliente con valor null.

Es como si el formulario está creando un nuevo modelo nuevo con los datos que se llenaron, olvidando así el modelo anterior que se le pasó como parametro a la Vista.

¿Que es lo que no estoy entendiendo aún sobre esto?

Comment: como defines la view ? usas por ejemplo @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ClienteId), porque necesitas que se envie en el submit

Comment: Uso los textboxfor si, pero en el formulario solamente cargo los datos model.Edad y model.Telefono con esos textboxfor. Entonces una vez enviado esos 2 datos SOLAMENTE con el formulario, el modelo parece que se olvida de model.ClienteId y model.NombreCliente que son propiedades del modelo que aunque no modifico fueron pasadas a la View desde el GET de Create.

Comment: si son valores que no modificas pero necesitas tenerlos en el modelo debes ponerlo en un @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.NombreCliente) sino no seran enviados en el body del request y por lo tanto no intervienen en el model binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el modelo completo sea parte del model binding debes asignar todas las propiedades a objeto html que sean parte del body del request

```
@Html.BeginForm("xxController", "Create", Method.Post){

   @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.NombreCliente) 
   @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ClienteId) 

   @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.NombreCliente) 
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Edad)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Telefono)

   <input type="submit" value="crear" />
}
```

si por ejemplo defines un `@Html.LabelFor()` este valor no aplica en el request y no se enviara el valor al servidor para el model binding, por eso se usa el `@Html.HiddenFor()`

Comment: Ahora me quedó claro y funciona todo ok. Gracias!

Comment: excelente, me estaba rompiendo el coco